# Setup apache nifi1.15.3 with oidc identity provider(keycloak) got errors

Tags: openid-connect, apache-nifi

i'm try to setup a apache nifi instance with oidc athentication,but it doesn'r work well,env info:

- **server**:**centos7,jdk8,apache nifi version1.15.3**
- **client**:**window10,Chrome v99.0.4844.51**

and here is conf files:
**nifi.properties:**

```
# Core Properties #
nifi.flow.configuration.file=./conf/flow.xml.gz
nifi.flow.configuration.archive.enabled=true
nifi.flow.configuration.archive.dir=./conf/archive/
nifi.flow.configuration.archive.max.time=30 days
nifi.flow.configuration.archive.max.storage=500 MB
nifi.flow.configuration.archive.max.count=
nifi.flowcontroller.autoResumeState=true
nifi.flowcontroller.graceful.shutdown.period=10 sec
nifi.flowservice.writedelay.interval=500 ms
nifi.administrative.yield.duration=30 sec
# If a component has no work to do (is "bored"), how long should we wait before checking again for work?
nifi.bored.yield.duration=10 millis
nifi.queue.backpressure.count=10000
nifi.queue.backpressure.size=1 GB

nifi.authorizer.configuration.file=./conf/authorizers.xml
nifi.login.identity.provider.configuration.file=./conf/login-identity-providers.xml
nifi.templates.directory=./conf/templates
nifi.ui.banner.text=DXTECH
nifi.ui.autorefresh.interval=30 sec
nifi.nar.library.directory=./lib
nifi.nar.library.autoload.directory=./extensions
nifi.nar.working.directory=./work/nar/
nifi.documentation.working.directory=./work/docs/components

####################
# State Management #
####################
nifi.state.management.configuration.file=./conf/state-management.xml
# The ID of the local state provider
nifi.state.management.provider.local=local-provider
# The ID of the cluster-wide state provider. This will be ignored if NiFi is not clustered but must be populated if running in a cluster.
nifi.state.management.provider.cluster=zk-provider
# Specifies whether or not this instance of NiFi should run an embedded ZooKeeper server
nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.start=false
# Properties file that provides the ZooKeeper properties to use if <nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.start> is set to true
nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.properties=./conf/zookeeper.properties

# H2 Settings
nifi.database.directory=./database_repository
nifi.h2.url.append=;LOCK_TIMEOUT=25000;WRITE_DELAY=0;AUTO_SERVER=FALSE

# Repository Encryption properties override individual repository implementation properties
nifi.repository.encryption.protocol.version=
nifi.repository.encryption.key.id=
nifi.repository.encryption.key.provider=
nifi.repository.encryption.key.provider.keystore.location=
nifi.repository.encryption.key.provider.keystore.password=

# FlowFile Repository
nifi.flowfile.repository.implementation=org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository
nifi.flowfile.repository.wal.implementation=org.apache.nifi.wali.SequentialAccessWriteAheadLog
nifi.flowfile.repository.directory=./flowfile_repository
nifi.flowfile.repository.checkpoint.interval=20 secs
nifi.flowfile.repository.always.sync=false
nifi.flowfile.repository.retain.orphaned.flowfiles=true

nifi.swap.manager.implementation=org.apache.nifi.controller.FileSystemSwapManager
nifi.queue.swap.threshold=20000

# Content Repository
nifi.content.repository.implementation=org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.FileSystemRepository
nifi.content.claim.max.appendable.size=1 MB
nifi.content.repository.directory.default=./content_repository
nifi.content.repository.archive.max.retention.period=7 days
nifi.content.repository.archive.max.usage.percentage=50%
nifi.content.repository.archive.enabled=true
nifi.content.repository.always.sync=false
nifi.content.viewer.url=../nifi-content-viewer/

# Provenance Repository Properties
nifi.provenance.repository.implementation=org.apache.nifi.provenance.WriteAheadProvenanceRepository

# Persistent Provenance Repository Properties
nifi.provenance.repository.directory.default=./provenance_repository
nifi.provenance.repository.max.storage.time=30 days
nifi.provenance.repository.max.storage.size=10 GB
nifi.provenance.repository.rollover.time=10 mins
nifi.provenance.repository.rollover.size=100 MB
nifi.provenance.repository.query.threads=2
nifi.provenance.repository.index.threads=2
nifi.provenance.repository.compress.on.rollover=true
nifi.provenance.repository.always.sync=false
# Comma-separated list of fields. Fields that are not indexed will not be searchable. Valid fields are:
# EventType, FlowFileUUID, Filename, TransitURI, ProcessorID, AlternateIdentifierURI, Relationship, Details
nifi.provenance.repository.indexed.fields=EventType, FlowFileUUID, Filename, ProcessorID, Relationship
# FlowFile Attributes that should be indexed and made searchable.  Some examples to consider are filename, uuid, mime.type
nifi.provenance.repository.indexed.attributes=
# Large values for the shard size will result in more Java heap usage when searching the Provenance Repository
# but should provide better performance
nifi.provenance.repository.index.shard.size=500 MB
# Indicates the maximum length that a FlowFile attribute can be when retrieving a Provenance Event from
# the repository. If the length of any attribute exceeds this value, it will be truncated when the event is retrieved.
nifi.provenance.repository.max.attribute.length=65536
nifi.provenance.repository.concurrent.merge.threads=2


# Volatile Provenance Respository Properties
nifi.provenance.repository.buffer.size=100000

# Component and Node Status History Repository
nifi.components.status.repository.implementation=org.apache.nifi.controller.status.history.VolatileComponentStatusRepository

# Volatile Status History Repository Properties
nifi.components.status.repository.buffer.size=1440
nifi.components.status.snapshot.frequency=1 min

# QuestDB Status History Repository Properties
nifi.status.repository.questdb.persist.node.days=14
nifi.status.repository.questdb.persist.component.days=3
nifi.status.repository.questdb.persist.location=./status_repository

# Site to Site properties
nifi.remote.input.host=
nifi.remote.input.secure=true
nifi.remote.input.socket.port=10443
nifi.remote.input.http.enabled=true
nifi.remote.input.http.transaction.ttl=30 sec
nifi.remote.contents.cache.expiration=30 secs

# web properties #
#############################################

# For security, NiFi will present the UI on 127.0.0.1 and only be accessible through this loopback interface.
# Be aware that changing these properties may affect how your instance can be accessed without any restriction.
# We recommend configuring HTTPS instead. The administrators guide provides instructions on how to do this.

#nifi.web.http.host=0.0.0.0
#nifi.web.http.port=8084
#nifi.web.http.network.interface.default=

#############################################
nifi.web.https.host=server-ip
nifi.web.https.port=9443
nifi.web.https.network.interface.default=
nifi.web.jetty.working.directory=./work/jetty
nifi.web.jetty.threads=200
nifi.web.max.header.size=16 KB
nifi.web.proxy.context.path=
nifi.web.proxy.host=
nifi.web.max.content.size=
nifi.web.max.requests.per.second=30000
nifi.web.max.access.token.requests.per.second=25
nifi.web.request.timeout=60 secs
nifi.web.request.ip.whitelist=
nifi.web.should.send.server.version=true

# Include or Exclude TLS Cipher Suites for HTTPS
nifi.web.https.ciphersuites.include=
nifi.web.https.ciphersuites.exclude=

# security properties #
nifi.sensitive.props.key=vw62HQM7KsPxX3dTH9QR6nDiNverd1TN
nifi.sensitive.props.key.protected=
nifi.sensitive.props.algorithm=NIFI_PBKDF2_AES_GCM_256
nifi.sensitive.props.additional.keys=

nifi.security.autoreload.enabled=false
nifi.security.autoreload.interval=10 secs

# 证书配置
nifi.security.keystore=./conf/keystore.jks
nifi.security.keystoreType=jks
nifi.security.keystorePasswd=B5m462aHkp8LFVB8JmKUx0P/BO/kdaseIXFjKa8Pn/Y
nifi.security.keyPasswd=B5m462aHkp8LFVB8JmKUx0P/BO/kdaseIXFjKa8Pn/Y
nifi.security.truststore=./conf/truststore.jks
nifi.security.truststoreType=jks
nifi.security.truststorePasswd=zu2mqAWCGYuj/hMwOVC7J1NYMdBP0hde3GhOdrl2QAM

nifi.security.allow.anonymous.authentication=false
nifi.security.user.authorizer=managed-authorizer
nifi.security.user.login.identity.provider=
#nifi.security.user.authorizer=single-user-authorizer
#nifi.security.user.login.identity.provider=single-user-provider
nifi.security.user.jws.key.rotation.period=PT1H
nifi.security.ocsp.responder.url=
nifi.security.ocsp.responder.certificate=

# OpenId Connect SSO Properties #
nifi.security.user.oidc.discovery.url=https://****/.well-known/openid-configuration
nifi.security.user.oidc.connect.timeout=5 secs
nifi.security.user.oidc.read.timeout=5 secs
nifi.security.user.oidc.client.id=***
nifi.security.user.oidc.client.secret=***-17dc1a17652f
nifi.security.user.oidc.preferred.jwsalgorithm=
nifi.security.user.oidc.additional.scopes=profile
nifi.security.user.oidc.claim.identifying.user=
nifi.security.user.oidc.fallback.claims.identifying.user=preferred_username

# Apache Knox SSO Properties #
#nifi.security.user.knox.url=
#nifi.security.user.knox.publicKey=
#nifi.security.user.knox.cookieName=hadoop-jwt
#nifi.security.user.knox.audiences=

# SAML Properties #
#nifi.security.user.saml.idp.metadata.url=https://wrdxtech.com/auth/realms/DataOps/protocol/saml/descriptor
#nifi.security.user.saml.sp.entity.id=org:apache:nifi:saml:sp
#nifi.security.user.saml.identity.attribute.name=
#nifi.security.user.saml.group.attribute.name=
#nifi.security.user.saml.metadata.signing.enabled=false
#nifi.security.user.saml.request.signing.enabled=false
#nifi.security.user.saml.want.assertions.signed=true
#nifi.security.user.saml.signature.algorithm=http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256
#nifi.security.user.saml.signature.digest.algorithm=http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256
#nifi.security.user.saml.message.logging.enabled=false
#nifi.security.user.saml.authentication.expiration=12 hours
#nifi.security.user.saml.single.logout.enabled=false
#nifi.security.user.saml.http.client.truststore.strategy=JDK
#nifi.security.user.saml.http.client.connect.timeout=30 secs
#nifi.security.user.saml.http.client.read.timeout=30 secs

# Identity Mapping Properties #
# These properties allow normalizing user identities such that identities coming from different identity providers
# (certificates, LDAP, Kerberos) can be treated the same internally in NiFi. The following example demonstrates normalizing
# DNs from certificates and principals from Kerberos into a common identity string:
#
# nifi.security.identity.mapping.pattern.dn=^CN=(.*?), OU=(.*?), O=(.*?), L=(.*?), ST=(.*?), C=(.*?)$
# nifi.security.identity.mapping.value.dn=$1@$2
# nifi.security.identity.mapping.transform.dn=NONE
# nifi.security.identity.mapping.pattern.kerb=^(.*?)/instance@(.*?)$
# nifi.security.identity.mapping.value.kerb=$1@$2
# nifi.security.identity.mapping.transform.kerb=UPPER

# Group Mapping Properties #
# These properties allow normalizing group names coming from external sources like LDAP. The following example
# lowercases any group name.
#
# nifi.security.group.mapping.pattern.anygroup=^(.*)$
# nifi.security.group.mapping.value.anygroup=$1
# nifi.security.group.mapping.transform.anygroup=LOWER

# cluster common properties (all nodes must have same values) #
nifi.cluster.protocol.heartbeat.interval=5 sec
nifi.cluster.protocol.heartbeat.missable.max=8
nifi.cluster.protocol.is.secure=false

# cluster node properties (only configure for cluster nodes) #
nifi.cluster.is.node=false
nifi.cluster.node.address=
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.port=11443
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.max.threads=50
nifi.cluster.node.event.history.size=25
nifi.cluster.node.connection.timeout=5 sec
nifi.cluster.node.read.timeout=5 sec
nifi.cluster.node.max.concurrent.requests=100
nifi.cluster.firewall.file=
nifi.cluster.flow.election.max.wait.time=5 mins
nifi.cluster.flow.election.max.candidates=

# cluster load balancing properties #
nifi.cluster.load.balance.host=
nifi.cluster.load.balance.port=6342
nifi.cluster.load.balance.connections.per.node=1
nifi.cluster.load.balance.max.thread.count=8
nifi.cluster.load.balance.comms.timeout=30 sec

# zookeeper properties, used for cluster management #
nifi.zookeeper.connect.string=
nifi.zookeeper.connect.timeout=10 secs
nifi.zookeeper.session.timeout=10 secs
nifi.zookeeper.root.node=/nifi
nifi.zookeeper.client.secure=false
nifi.zookeeper.security.keystore=
nifi.zookeeper.security.keystoreType=
nifi.zookeeper.security.keystorePasswd=
nifi.zookeeper.security.truststore=
nifi.zookeeper.security.truststoreType=
nifi.zookeeper.security.truststorePasswd=
nifi.zookeeper.jute.maxbuffer=

# Zookeeper properties for the authentication scheme used when creating acls on znodes used for cluster management
# Values supported for nifi.zookeeper.auth.type are "default", which will apply world/anyone rights on znodes
# and "sasl" which will give rights to the sasl/kerberos identity used to authenticate the nifi node
# The identity is determined using the value in nifi.kerberos.service.principal and the removeHostFromPrincipal
# and removeRealmFromPrincipal values (which should align with the kerberos.removeHostFromPrincipal and kerberos.removeRealmFromPrincipal
# values configured on the zookeeper server).
nifi.zookeeper.auth.type=
nifi.zookeeper.kerberos.removeHostFromPrincipal=
nifi.zookeeper.kerberos.removeRealmFromPrincipal=

# kerberos #
#nifi.kerberos.krb5.file=

# kerberos service principal #
#nifi.kerberos.service.principal=
#nifi.kerberos.service.keytab.location=

# kerberos spnego principal #
#nifi.kerberos.spnego.principal=
#nifi.kerberos.spnego.keytab.location=
#nifi.kerberos.spnego.authentication.expiration=12 hours

# external properties files for variable registry
# supports a comma delimited list of file locations
nifi.variable.registry.properties=

# analytics properties #
nifi.analytics.predict.enabled=false
nifi.analytics.predict.interval=3 mins
nifi.analytics.query.interval=5 mins
nifi.analytics.connection.model.implementation=org.apache.nifi.controller.status.analytics.models.OrdinaryLeastSquares
nifi.analytics.connection.model.score.name=rSquared
nifi.analytics.connection.model.score.threshold=.90

# runtime monitoring properties
nifi.monitor.long.running.task.schedule=
nifi.monitor.long.running.task.threshold=

# Create automatic diagnostics when stopping/restarting NiFi.

# Enable automatic diagnostic at shutdown.
nifi.diagnostics.on.shutdown.enabled=false

# Include verbose diagnostic information.
nifi.diagnostics.on.shutdown.verbose=false

# The location of the diagnostics folder.
nifi.diagnostics.on.shutdown.directory=./diagnostics

# The maximum number of files permitted in the directory. If the limit is exceeded, the oldest files are deleted.
nifi.diagnostics.on.shutdown.max.filecount=10

# The diagnostics folder's maximum permitted size in bytes. If the limit is exceeded, the oldest files are deleted.
nifi.diagnostics.on.shutdown.max.directory.size=10 MB
```

others config files are default,server start up without any error,but when request send,i got server errors,here is the console:
[image: console errors]
details-

- 1st line - url:https: //server:port/nifi-api/access/kerberos
  error:Kerberos ticket login not supported by this NiFi.
- 2nd line - url:https: //server:port/nifi-api/access/oidc/exchange
  error:The login request identifier was not found in the request.
  Unable to continue.
- 3rd line - url:https: //server:port/nifi-api/access/saml/login/exchange error:SAML
  support is not configured.
- 4th line - url:https: //server:port/nifi-api/flow/current-user error:No
  applicable policies could be found. Contact the system administrator.

my guess: as the browser didn't enven redirect me to keycloak login page,i think the oidc conf did not working, so nifi didn't know which authorizer was configured,but there're so few info from official document,i don't konw what's wrong, someone please help :)

Comment: you can find valuable info on how to do this in https://bryanbende.com/development/2017/10/03/apache-nifi-openid-connect

Comment: yes,that's one of my reference to do this,i put an account in authorizer.xml,but it still didn't work. same errors.

Comment: maybe something that is not in the article: we commented out the single-user-authorizer at the bottom of the conf/authorizers.xml configuration file

Comment: @BenoitOrihuela yes,I tried to  " commented out the single-user-authorizer at the bottom of the conf/authorizers.xml" , but still didn't work. same errors. could you please show me your whole nifi.properties file,and your nifi version?

Comment: did you create an user in your keyclock realm whose user-name must match 'nifi.security.user.oidc.client.id' ? also you must give this nifi user 'view the user interface' grant  via Policies menu

Comment: a lot thks to whom concerned, I found out it's some nginx proxy problem,same conf now work fine :)